# Getting JMS Correlation Id after aggregation in mule

Tags: jms, mule

I have two JMS outbound messages that are received in a scatter gather to aggregate the two messages from the clients. then i need to use a splitter to split the messages and then send them one by one to another flow via jms:

```
<flow name="clientoneFlow1" doc:name="clientoneFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8081" path="client1" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <component class="SalesOrder" doc:name="Java"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="clientOne" doc:name="Property"/>
    <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE" value="1" doc:name="Property"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="client1.publish" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:object-to-jmsmessage-transformer doc:name="Object to JMSMessage"/>
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>

<flow name="clienttwoFlow1" doc:name="clienttwoFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8081" path="client2" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <component class="SalesOrder2" doc:name="Java"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="clientTwo" doc:name="Property"/>
    <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE" value="2" doc:name="Property"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="client2.publish" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:object-to-jmsmessage-transformer doc:name="Object to JMSMessage"/>
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>

<flow name="integration-internetsolutionsFlow1" doc:name="integration-internetsolutionsFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" path="esb"/>
    <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
        <processor-chain>
            <flow-ref name="clientoneFlow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
            <logger message="Client One: #[message.correlationSequence]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </processor-chain>
        <processor-chain>
            <flow-ref name="clienttwoFlow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
            <logger message="Client Two: #[message.correlationSequence]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </processor-chain>
    </scatter-gather>
    <logger level="INFO"  message="Combined Payload: #[message.payload]" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <splitter enableCorrelation="ALWAYS" expression="#[payload]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
    <logger message="after splitter = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="Corr after splitter = #[message.correlationId] and group = #[message.correlationGroupSize]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="validation.queue" doc:name="JMS"/>
</flow>

<flow name="validateFlow1" doc:name="validateFlow1">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ" queue="validation.queue"/>
    <logger message="splinter payload = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="splitter corr Id = #[message.correlationId]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

but after the splitter the correlation Ids of the two clients have disappeared and assigned the same correlation Id. How can i retrieve the correlation Ids after the splitter? and in the validation flow consume the messages according to correlationId

Comment: Why you want to use splitter ??

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i need to split the message, edit the data in the individual messages, aggregate the data again after the data has been edited. and then send the message back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an expression splitter you will use the list of payloads to split, and therefore a new MuleEvent on each splitted branch.

If you use a collection splitter, you'll use the [EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule/mule-core/3.5.0/org/mule/util/collection/EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.java#EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy), that will handle correctly the split of a [MessageCollection](https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleMessageCollection.html).

Therefor, replace the **splitter** with a **collection-splitter**.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a splitter to split a message after **scatter-gather** ....

After **scatter-gather** the message is automatically a combined and messages can be extracted in following form :-
`#[message.payload[0]]`  and `#[message.payload[1]]` 
example :-

```
<logger level="INFO"  message="Payload1 of clientoneFlow1 : #[message.payload[0]] and clienttwoFlow1: #[message.payload[1]] " doc:name="Logger"/>
```

So yo can remove the splitter and try